# macvlan device do not honor smaller mtu than physical device

Tags: linux, network-interface, ping, macvlan

I have a use case to create multiple MACVLAN devices from the same physical ethernet device. The requirement is also that some MACVLANs could offer jumbo packets (MTU=9215) and some disallow jumbo packets and support only small frames.
I kept MTU=9000 for the physical device, and created required MACVLAN device. Noticed that MACVLAN device by default got the MTU of 9000 and were also working fine with jumbo frames (tested via ping with jumbo packets).. but then post changing the MTU of the MACVLan to 1500, it kept on working fine with jumbo frames. Below example shows just one MACVLAN

```
$ ip link add K9AT9i1G2x link eth6 type macvlan mode bridge
$ ip link set dev K9AT9i1G2x mtu 1500
$ ip a
123: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:60:16:a6:90:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::260:16ff:fea6:903a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

129: K9AT9i1G2x@eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:c7:36:3f:9a:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.15.40/21 scope global K9AT9i1G2x
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b8c7:36ff:fe3f:9a76/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Below ping worked, even though MTU of macvlan device is set to 1500 -

```
 # ping -c 3 -M do -s 8972 192.168.15.40

PING 192.168.15.40 (192.168.15.40) 8972(9000) bytes of data.
8980 bytes from 192.168.15.40: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=27.0 ms
8980 bytes from 192.168.15.40: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.955 ms
8980 bytes from 192.168.15.40: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=5.33 ms

--- 192.168.15.40 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.955/11.098/27.009/11.391 ms
```

Can somebody please suggest, how do I restrict only smaller packet transport in this case ?

Comment: This works for me in a test on kernel 5.17.x when using veth interfaces (I get the expected `ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1500` only after lowering mtu) . So this could be a 1/ kernel bug that was fixed before if you're using an older kernel, 2/ a driver bug specific to your NIC 3/ a routing issue if you kept an IP address in the same LAN on an other related interface at the same time. What is your kernel version and distribution? Can you provide the output of `ip route show match 192.168.15.40; ip neigh show to 192.168.15.40`?

Comment: My kernel version is 5.3.18 and is on SLES15 SP2 OS distro.

Comment: $ ip route show match 192.168.15.40
default via x.x.x.x dev eth0
192.168.8.0/21 dev K9AT9i1G2x proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.40

Comment: $ ip neigh show to 192.168.15.40
$   # Doesnt give any output

Comment: My bad.. gave wrong output from self system. Below are correct output. (Kernel version is same as 5.3.18

Comment: $ ip route show match 192.168.15.40 default via x.x.x.x dev eth0
192.168.8.0/21 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.101

Comment: $ ip neigh show to 192.168.15.40
192.168.15.40 dev eth1 lladdr ba:c7:36:3f:9a:76 STALE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137568/discussion-between-smash-and-a-b).

Comment: So FWIW, testing in the opposite direction of my previous test, I get the same result as OP.